# How do I end a process based of a keyword in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, exit

How can I end a process containing a certain keyword, for example

```
end.process("firefox.exe")
```

something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import psutil

p_name = "firefox.exe"

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name() == p_name:
        p.kill()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!